# How to calcuate the calories burned during running

Tags: running, calories

I would like to know are there any forumla for that?

The formula should better take the **age, weight, height, gender 
running disatance, time** for the calcuation

Ref calcuator
http://www.mapmyrun.com/improve/calorie_calculator/

Are there any forumla can get the calories burned? Thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The answer seems quite academic , I would like to have one formula.

Comment: The _answer_ is quite academic, yes. The _question_ is pretty much the same as yours. But that's for other people to decide. Regarding your question, this is as close as I got with google and it includes most everything you asked for: http://fitnowtraining.com/2012/01/formula-for-calories-burned/

Comment: Yes I have googled for a while. As the forumla in the link is using heart rate that it seems not suitable for my case . Thanks your help anyway